# Paypal Checkout call back function is not calling

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, checkout

I am using Paypal Checkout for payment. when I added a card to the payment page of PayPal then hit continue button. There is no callback I get in my app. This is working properly in previous. Here is my code

**AppDelegate-**

```
let config = CheckoutConfig(
                 clientID: "AZaq0yHkHgUgdEpyhS4EDEu0AT7ydGkAPae3v5oF3bsVRHFQksFOLC6sQ2UN4Io",
                 returnUrl: "com.google.demo://paypalpay",
                 environment: .sandbox
             )
Checkout.set(config: config)
```

**View Controller -**

```
@IBAction func clickOnPay(_ sender: Any) {
    
    Checkout.start( createOrder: { createOrderAction in
        let amount = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .usd, value: "500")
        let purchaseUnit = PurchaseUnit(amount: amount)
        let order = OrderRequest(intent: .capture, purchaseUnits: [purchaseUnit])
        createOrderAction.create(order: order)
        
    }, onApprove: { approval in
        print("State.correlationIDs: \(State.correlationIDs)")
        approval.actions.capture { (response, error) in
            print("This is Responce===\(response!)")
            
        }
        
    }, onCancel: {          // Optionally use this closure to respond to the user
                            // the user canceling the paysheet
      //self.showPopup(status: "cancel")
        print("cancel")
        
    }, onError: { error in  // Optionally use this closure to respond to the user
                            // experiencing an error in the payment experience
      //self.showPopup(status: "fail")
        print(error)
    })
}
```

My client id and return key are the same which are included in my PayPal account.